# Jenkins Plugin: Select filled by model

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to use something like this:

```
public ListBoxModel doFillGoalTypeItems() {
    ListBoxModel items = new ListBoxModel();
    for (BuildGoal goal : getBuildGoals()) {
        items.add(goal.getDisplayName(), goal.getId());
    }
    return items;
}

<f:entry field="goalType" title="Choose Goal Type">
    <f:select />
</f:entry
```

That sample works perfectly in a configuration section, but the select is not filled when used in a RootAction. All I get is the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/jenkins/my-plugin/null 404 (Not Found)
No matching rule was found on <com.my.plugin.MyRootAction@1aa70942> for "/null"
```

I've already tried the doFillXyzItems method either inside or outside the descriptor and nothing seems to help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer in the [jenkins developer forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/jenkinsci-dev/TgNiBeYEgz4/J658JsMGJv4J). The descriptor variable needs to be set before the selects. So, something like this needs to be done:

```
<j:set var="descriptor" value="${it.descriptor}"/>
```

After that, the AJAX calls work and the selects will be filled as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this myself and came to the conclusion that the descriptor architecture doesn't work with rootActions.

You can look at my abandoned project (groovy and groovy forms) for some inspiration (and other rootActions)

In the [classes](https://github.com/JeremyMarshall/job-dsl-stub/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/jenkinsci/plugins/jobdsl/stub/DslLink.groovy) you do things like this

```
@Extension
public class DslLink extends ManagementLink implements Describable<DslLink> {
    private Factory factory = new Factory();
    private String dslInterface
```

And then in the jelly/[groovy forms](https://github.com/JeremyMarshall/job-dsl-stub/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/jobdsl/stub/DslLink/index.jelly)

```
    <j:forEach  var="cat" items="${it.factory.categoriesAsList}" >
      <tr>
        <td><f:readOnlyTextbox value="${cat.name}"/></td>
        <td><f:readOnlyTextbox value="${cat.description}"/></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
```

I think the syntax is slightly different for jelly

As a separate resource, the [file-scm plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/filesystem_scm-plugin) predates the databound constructor/descriptor architecture so populates jelly views the same way that rootActions do.

You might be better to ask the people on the [jenkins developer forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/jenkinsci-dev) too

Comment: The biggest issue here is I'm intended to use dynamic filled lists like this one https://github.com/jenkinsci/ui-samples-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/ui_samples/DynamicDropDownListBox.java

Comment: Have you set the urlName http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Action.html#getUrlName() . I spent a bit of time looking at this and came to the conclusion that rootActions are a readOnly/Informational type interaction without some heavy lifting. The scriptApproval plugin tends to use javascript to add interactions https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/scripts/ScriptApproval/index.jelly